# Amazon secret keys and Heroku

Tags: git, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, heroku

I'm using S3 in this application for uploaded files, as Heroku has a read-only filesystem.  How can I give my s3.yml to Heroku, but avoid checking it into the main repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out http://docs.heroku.com/config-vars, the first example on the page is exactly what you are trying to do.

Edit '2015:  page now at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars and it's the second page you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to create a new **local-branch** where you modify .gitignore so **secret-file** can be pushed to heroku.
**DON'T** push this branch to your Github repo.

To push non-master branch to heroku, use:

```
git push heroku secret-branch:master
```

More info can be found on:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced-linking-local-branches-to-remote-apps

Use `heroku run bash` and then `ls` to check whether your secret-file have been pushed on to heroku or not

Benefits over the other solution:
Keep the **secret-file** in your favorite format ;)