# How can I deploy a secure hash key to Heroku without pushing it to GitHub?

Tags: security, heroku, github

We have an app that contains security hashes, keys, and pins. We use GitHub to version our code and Heroku for hosting. I know GitHub was hacked a year or two ago, plus I am sure it's bad practice to push any secure files to GitHub.

What is the best process to deploy our app and push code to GitHub, but NOT push this security file to GitHub while still allowing us to send it to Heroku?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813702/amazon-secret-keys-and-heroku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use Config Vars with Heroku Toolbelt

You can set environment variables via the command line with [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/). The process is [described in detail](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) in the Heroku documentation, but as an example:

```
# Set FOO as an environment variable for your app.
$ heroku config:set FOO=bar

# Access FOO from inside your Heroku app.
puts ENV['FOO']
```